# Directory exists is producing inconsistant results on desktop vs server

Tags: c#, windows

I have a **C# program** which checks if a specific directory exists.

It is simply doing:

```
Directory.Exists(path).
```

I tried other ways as well. Using ***DirectoryInfo*** and using ***AlphaFS***

On my local machine, the path exists.  When I run the same program on a server with the same credentials it doesn't exist.

I wonder if it is a group policy issue. But I am able to go up one level and see it.

***\server\volume\share\sub*** directory - Doesn't exist remotely but on my desktop it does
***\server\volume\share*** - Does exist both on my desktop and remote server

**Update**
I forgot to mention, that since I had access to my desktop, I got the ACL information.
None of the groups were able to translate.

I really just want to get this application to behave the same way is on the server and find out why it is behaving differently.

**Update 2**
These are physical servers.
My desktop is Liquid VDI

Below is the code:

```
 var path = txtPath.Text;
        using (var user = new Impersonation(fuserdomain, fc_user, fc_pass))
        {
            var alphaExists = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.Exists(path);
            var alphaDIExists = new Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.DirectoryInfo(path).Exists;
            var SystemExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            var SystemDIExists = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).Exists;
            var AlphaHasFiles = false;
            var AlphaDIHasFiles = false;
            var SystemHasFiles = false;
            var SystemDIHasFiles = false;
            try
            {
                Directory.GetFiles(path);
                AlphaHasFiles = true;
            }
            catch {  }
            try
            {
                new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
                AlphaDIHasFiles = true;
            }
            catch {  }
            try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
                SystemHasFiles = true;
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
                SystemDIHasFiles = true;
            }
            catch { }

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("alphaExists: {0}\nalphaDIExists: {1}\nSystemExists: {2}\nSystemDIExists: {3}\nAlphaGetFiles: {4}\nAlphaDIGetFiles: {5}\nSystemGetFiles: {6}\nSystemDIGetFiles: {7}\n", alphaExists, alphaDIExists, SystemExists, SystemDIExists, AlphaHasFiles, AlphaDIHasFiles, SystemHasFiles, SystemDIHasFiles));
        }
```

**Update 3**
Although I have workaround this issue; I am still not sure why I would have a difference between my desktop and server. Is there any tool that can help me see where the issue may be?

Comment: Probably a permission problem for that specific directory

Comment: have you tried `Server.MapPath('~');` ?

Comment: @thanatorr. I am putting the full path

Comment: Kindly cross check whether the specified folder path is available in the server, secondly check the folder permissions in the server.

Comment: @steve. When running the code from my desktop, I was able to get the permissions. What I noticed is that none of the permissions were able to be translated.  So all the permissions were lagacy.  But curious why it didn't work on a server but on the desktop

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the same thing with File.Exists.  I never found an answer and finally threw in the towel, I simply try to use it and catch the exception.

Robust code has to catch it anyway, all the test does is avoid trying if the file or directory is not there.  (And the PITA that Visual Studio no longer as any way to ignore an exception on a certain line.  No problem runtime, annoying in development.)

Comment: FIle.Exists doesnt throw an exception when a path isnt found.  Also, you solution is not what I am looking to accomplish

Comment: @H20rider I meant to open the file and use the FileNotFoundException as the the primary way of detecting it's not existence.

Comment: Loren.  My program is scanning all the file and meta data.   So the only thing I can try is to try to get the files.  I assume that wouldn't work. But will try it

Comment: @H20rider I've never had a problem with reading the directory.  It's only the .Exists functions that I have had problems with--always returning false on UNC paths.  The program that gave me this problem contains two reads of entire directory structures with zero problems but is completely incapable of validating whether a file exists to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete shot in the dark, since we don't have *any* specific details to go on. e.g. Is the server you're talking about physically yours, or is it a cloud-based server service?

I'd guess that your machine is an older operating system than the server, and the folder that you're trying to access is one of those special folders that has become more locked down with more recent operating systems (particularly on server operating systems) like the "Program Files" folder. So even though the folder exists on both, the method works on your machine but not on the server, due to permissions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I gave that a try with no luck.  I added more details.  my desktop is LVDI and the server is physycal

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the Impersonation class in your code is not part of the dot net framework. Googling finds a couple of implementations. Where does it come from and How confident are you that it actually works in your scenario?

For example, if you remove the Impersonation code, and actually run it as that user, does that make it work?

One other clarification... When you say
\server\volume\share
Do you mean this is a network location (e.g. a UNC location), so is the same network path you are trying to access from both machines? If so, this would open up new possibilities for problems like firewalls, etc... Is that location on either of the two machines that we know about from the question, or a different location?

Comment: Good questions. The problem was discovered in a windows server logged in as that user.  To simplify the problem, I am using my own impersonation class in a simple winform,  The same code and on my local desktop (LVDI) and the server have 2 separate results.  So you would think it was a firewall, but I am able to access the \\server\volume of that path. and yes I am using a UNC pat